# Error Message JS WebConsole "Child create error: error index.html:74:17"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting the following error message when clicking create button on a form. The create option is working fine on the RestClient.

"Child create error: error  index.html:74:17" `in the web console. No error messages when running from Visual Studios:

```
// Called with "createForm" onSubmit
        function createChild() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: rootURL,
                dataType: "json",
                data: formToJSONCreate(),
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log('Child created successfully');
                    clearCreateForm();
                    displayList();
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Child create error: ' + textStatus + "" + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: It is executing your `error` handler of your `$.ajax` call. Are you getting a 200 OK response ? Are you getting a response which can be parsed to JSON ?

Comment: When I click create "Child create error: error  index.html:74:21" appears. When I run it through the RESTClient I get the 200 OK respons?